# Android: Reading data from bluetooth when available

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream

I'm developing an app to communicate with an Atmega328p microcontroller via bluetooth. The app will request data whenever it needs, sending a simple "newData" string to de Atmega. 
What i need to do, is read this data as soon as it is available. If I read it immediatly after I request it, it isn't yet available and the data is readed in the next request. My question is, is there a way to detect when a new data is available, something like inputstream.available()>0, without using an endless loop?
I've tried with BroadcastReciver but couldn't find a way to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using Bluetooth le or standard bluetooth??

Comment: I'm using standard bluetooth.